Summation of Factorial
Finding summation of factorial when they are in the denominator is quite simply due to expansions of e as well as by formation of telescopic series. But when factorial happen to be in the numerators they tend to cause a lot of trouble to me, don't really know how to deal with them at that point. I got stuck in a question that said let
$$ S = \sum_{i=0}^{2023} (i)^2(i+1)! $$
Find the remainder of S when divided by 2023. I tried simplifying the summation but couldn't find a way through. I also noticed that $2023=7.17.17$ which still didn't seem to help as only one term would had such a case in the summation.
Any help on clarify summation with factorial on numerator would be appreciated.

When they’re in the numerator, $ n! = \int_0^\infty, t^n e^{-t},dt$ can help.

$$S = \sum^{2023}_{i=1}i^2(i+1)! \underset{\pm 4}= \sum^{2023}_{i=1}(i^2+4-4)(i+1)!$$
$$S= \sum^{2023}_{i=1}(i-2)(i+2)!+4(i+1)! \underset{(n+k)!=(n+k)(n+k-1)!}= \sum^{2023}_{i=1}(i+3)!-5(i+2)!+4(i+1)!$$
$$S = \sum^{2023}_{i=1}(i+3)!-(i+2)!-4\left((i+2)!-(i+1)!\right)$$
You can now telescope this sum and then its the usual.
$$S=(2026)!-4(2025)!+2$$
Since you require the remainder after dividing with 2023, it's pretty obvious the first two terms have a 2023 factor in them and hence, your remainder is just 2.
WA sum and WA closed form

Hadn't even thought of getting the numerator in similar terms of i+1 and beyond to make it into a telescopic, thanks alot.

@MahitChopra telescoping is all about achieving $f(n)-f(n\pm k)$ form roughly (not a very solid telescoping form notation but i hope you get the idea), good luck for your exams!

Thanks alot, hope you have a great December.
